# Is there a "two of three keys needed" encryption?

Tags: encryption, keys

Sorry if this question is stupid, but is there an encryption algorithm where a message is encrypted with a set of *n* keys which can then be deciphered with any sufficiently large subset of those? E.g. encrypt with 3 keys and any 2 are sufficient to decipher the message.
AFAIK some blockchain wallets have a functionality similar to this.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing

Comment: This looks pretty much like what I was looking for. :-)

Comment: This can be done easily by hand, see [What is a simple way to “2 out of 3”-secure a 24 words phrase without computers?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/171225/6211), or [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/62957/555) for the math.